# Регулярное выражение с неполным фрагментом

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня дан файл с символами. Необохдимо определить максимальную длинну цепочки вида XYZ, при этом сам фрагмент может быть не полным.

Полное описание задачи:
`Текстовый файл состоит не более чем из 10**6 символов X, Y и Z. Определите максимальную длину цепочки вида XYZXYZXYZ... (составленной из фрагментов XYZ, последний фрагмент может быть неполным).`

Пример: XYZXYZXYXX - 8, XYZXYZ - 6
На данный момент имеют вот такой скрипт:

```py
import re

with open('file.txt') as file:
    line = file.readline()

res = re.finditer(r'(XYZ)+', line)
mg = 0
for x in res:
    mg = max(len(x.group()), mg)
print(mg)
```

Как правильно составить нужное мне выражение? (обычным скриптом я найти смогу, у меня задача именно регулярными выражениями)

Comment: А может быть AAZXYZXYBB — 6?

Comment: Не может. Не корретно описал задачу. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: `(XYZ)+(XY|X)` ?

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Напишите это в ответ и я отмечу как решенное.
Конечное выглядит вот так: ```(XYZ)+(XYZ|XY|X)```

Comment: @AlexanderChernykh Не совсем верно. Ваш вариант не поймает просто `XYZ`. @AlexeyTen правильно написал (если взять полный текст его сообщения :) - `(XYZ)+(XY|X)?`. Или можно в вашей записи `(XYZ)+(XYZ|XY|X)?`. А если "последний фрагмент может быть неполным", но вдруг он единственный в последовательности, и это допустимо, то `(XYZ)*(XYZ|XY|X)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярные выражения лишь находят совпадения, они не могут найти самую длинную подстроку. Поэтому сначала нужно найти все совпадения, а потом использовать `max()`, что вы и делаете в своём коде.

Регулярное выражение тут будет

```py
(?:XYZ)+(?:X(?:YZ?))?
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/1ujB1m/2). **Подробности**:

- `(?:XYZ)+` - одна и более последовательностей `XYZ`
- `(?:X(?:YZ?))?` - опциональная последовательность: `X`, потом может быть `Y`, и только если есть уже `XY`, потом `Z`.

См. [пример кода](https://ideone.com/KEzq9O):

```py
import re

with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        matches = re.findall(r'(?:XYZ)+(?:X(?:YZ?))?', line)
        if matches:
            longest = max(matches, key=len)
            print(f'{line}: {longest} (Длина: {len(longest)})')
        else:
            print(f'{line}: NO MATCH')
```

Результат:

```py
XYZXYZXYXX XYZXYZ: XYZXYZXY (Длина: 8)
XYZXY XYZXYZ: XYZXYZ (Длина: 6)
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy [Да](https://ideone.com/QakkHb).